# How to restore Visual Studio Code terminal dropdown - it has become icons

Tags: visual-studio-code, terminal, drop-down-menu, restore

Instead of the classic dropdown on the right side of the terminal window in VS Code, showing different terminal options I can select from, I now have a series of icons and no dropdown at all. See screen image at the link StackOverflow provided.

How do I restore the original format with the dropdown terminal selection options?

I am on a Windows 10 machine running VS Code
Version: 1.56.2 (user setup)
Commit: 054a9295330880ed74ceaedda236253b4f39a335
Date: 2021-05-12T17:13:13.157Z
Electron: 12.0.4
Chrome: 89.0.4389.114
Node.js: 14.16.0
V8: 8.9.255.24-electron.0
OS: Windows_NT x64 10.0.19042